# Injection of chrome extension content script to dynamically instantiated iframes

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, content-script

In chrome extension manifest I have support for iframes.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
      "css": [],
      "js": [
        'someScript.js'
      ],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
```

Everything is fine until iframes are instantiated during page actions, not before page load. When iframe will be created later content scripts are not injected to new iframe. How can I make content scripts work in dynamically instantiated iframes?

Comment: AFAICT all you need is to add ["match_about_blank": true](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match_about_blank).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks.